# Labels for explicitly plotted stacked histogram pandas from series with datetimeindex

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I've got a pandas series and want to plot a stacked histogram by using a filter to create two new (smaller) series. This is some dummy data, but my actual series has a (non-unique) datetimeindex.

```
d =

0     2520
1        0
2     1083
3        0
4        0
5     1260
6      960
7       13
8      300
9      433
10    1860
11    1920
12      13
13       0
14    2460
15    2472
16      12
17      60
18    2832
19      12

d1 = d[0:19:2]
d2 = d[1:17:3]
d1.hist(color = 'r', label = 'foo')
d2.hist(label = 'bar')
```

However, the labels don't show up. I've looked at the pandas [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html#histograms), which shows everything working when plotted from different columns of a dataframe, but in my case I can't combine these into a single dataframe since they have different indices (and lengths). Any suggestions?

Comment: Not clear what you want here. A stacked hist has to share x-values, and you've set your two data frames up so that they don't share any x-values, so there's nothing to stack.  If you want to stack them by order, you could reset the indexes, merge them into one data frame, rename the columns, and use "plot(kind='hist',stacked=True)

Comment: @iayork --'they don't share any x-values'-- depending on how big the bins are, what I want to show is that in d1 (say) there are more high values than d2, so look at the shape of the data in comparison

Comment: @iayork that said, I think your suggestion of resetting and merging would be good, but my series currently have a datetimeindex - how do I reset that? And does it matter if they don't have the same length?

Comment: I have slightly adjusted the question now that I understand the problem better - I had an overlapping datetimeindex which meant I couldn't concatenate the two series back together into a dataframe, but once reset to just an integer index it was no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @iayork's comments above, the following works:

import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([d1, d2], axis = 1)

df.plot(kind = hist)

Note: df.hist() plots individual histograms for each column within the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Set the column names and plot one by one over a single subplot:

```
d1.columns = ['foo']
d2.columns = ['bar']
f = plt.figure()
_ax = f.add_subplot(111)
d1.plot(color='r',kind='hist', stacked=True, ax=_ax)
d2.plot(kind='hist', stacked=True, ax=_ax)
```